# select the id value of selected row in gridview

Tags: c#

How can get the value of selected row in grid view without events function ?
I using something like that but it doesn't work:

```
   int select= Convert.ToInt32(gvMember.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
```

Comment: how doesn't it work? What's the data type of your `id`, looks like it belongs to the first column.

Comment: Do you not want to use the built in events? SelectedIndex?

Comment: @KingKing i get the Error of index Error

Comment: @hutchonoid No i have a gridview and i using a rightclick menu ,so when the users click one of the items in menu i should pass  the value selected row of gridview

Comment: Is this an asp .net GridView and not Forms app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you don't actually know how to select a row, you have to select a row by **clicking on the row header**, or if you want it simpler, just use this code:

```
gvMember.SelectionMode=DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
```

then you can just click on the row itself. That way, it will ensure that there is always at least 1 row selected. If you don't want that full row select mode, you have to check the `SelectedRows.Count` and notify user to select row by clicking on the row header like this:

```
if(gvMember.SelectedRows.Count > 0){
  int select= Convert.ToInt32(gvMember.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
  //... other code
} else {
  MessageBox.Show("There is not any row selected, you select row by clicking on the row header!");
}
```

If you want to get the id corresponding to the current row, you can use the `CurrentRow` property:

```
int select= Convert.ToInt32(gvMember.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
```